# type conversion in apache camel

Tags: java, apache, spring-boot, apache-camel, integration

I am pretty new to Apache Camel and currently I am making a test project. Currently I am trying to write some previously processed objects from custom class into a file using the file component (i dont know a better option).

```
from("direct:processedDecimals")
            .to("file:data/output")
```

but i have the following problem

```
   Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: Add{x=5.63, y=78.016} of type: org.example.math.Add on: Message[ID-NTB828-1537281187742-0-10]. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: org.example.math.Add to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value Add{x=5.63, y=78.016}. Exchange[ID-NTB828-1537281187742-0-9]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: org.example.math.Add to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value Add{x=5.63, y=78.016}]
```

I saw on the internet that some people suggests writing custom TypeConverter and then register it in a file in the WEB-INF folder. But I am using SpringBoot and its internal Tomcat and I dont have this directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert body to String with *convertBodyTo(String.class)*, it will use *toString* method on Your object to make a conversion:

```
from("direct:processedDecimals")
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .to("file:data/output");
```

This should write 'Add{x=5.63, y=78.016}' into the file.

Comment: you are right. I did something similar and i dont face the same problem anymore. Thank you